# ItemfrequencyPlot - Arules package to show bottom frequency itemsets

Tags: r, arules, market-basket-analysis

I want to see the bottom frequency items in the transaction data, how can i see that?

**code:**

```
a_list <- list(
c("a","b","c"),    
c("a","b"),
c("a","b","d"),
c("c","e"),
c("a","b","d","e")
)

trans <- as(a_list, "transactions")

itemFrequencyPlot(trans)
```

*PS: I am integrating this on a shiny platform.*

Comment: Could you provide the expected output

Comment: I expect to see d and e with their frequencies plotted if i put bottom two elements mentioned. It should work exactly opposite to the TopN functionality that arules package provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itemFrequency()` and then sort or filter the frequencies you like and plot them with `barplot()`.

```
R> barplot(sort(itemFrequency(trans), decreasing=TRUE))
```